# Some biblatex labels do not appear depending on their position

Tags: biblatex, biber

I'm using BibLaTex with Biber to generate my bib­li­og­ra­phy.

Unfortunatelly, I'm struggling with a very strange behaviour concerning the displaying of the blibliography labels: Some labels are not shown, depending on their position within the text. That is, on some position the label appears as expected, on another text position the label "shows" up as in

[image]

Now, when I insert another reference before the missing one, I get the expected result:

[image]

How can I fix this strange issue?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This *could* be the unwanted consequence of tinkering with the `ibidem` or `idem` mechanisms included in some styles. However, without a minimal working example it's impossible to say more.

Comment: The problem disappeared by using another BiBLaTeX citation style.